# how to create date check in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

When creating a table in postgres of type time its very simple to set a time check, to make sure that what is entered has to be between two times like so:

```
extime       TIME           NOT NULL,
check(extime > '09:00:00' and extime < '18:00:00')
```

I want to do something similar with a date field

```
exdate       DATE           NOT NULL,
```

to have it between the beginning and end of june.

is anybody able to give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest approach would be to extract the month from the date, and make sure it's in June:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    exdate DATE NOT NULL,
    CHECK (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM exdate) = 6)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't had a chance to try it myself but im assuming this would be valid? (sorry for poor formatting)

    CHECK (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM exdate) = 6)

    CHECK (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM exdate) = 2015)

    CHECK (EXTRACT (DAY FROM exdate) > 0)

    CHECK (EXTRACT (DAY FROM exdate) < 31)

Comment: @ayoolaadedeji looks about right - probably missing commas between the constraints though.